# Proving $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is a norm in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a polygonal domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

I want to proof that $\|\nabla (\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is a norm on $H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$, $\Omega$ a polygonal domain.

**Does the fact that $\Omega$ is a polygonal domain, changes the usual proof somehow?**

For the non-degeneracy I have that

$0=\|\nabla (u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \implies 0=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 dx$

$\implies \nabla (u)=0 $ a.e

$\implies u=c \in \mathbb{R} $ a.e

If $u$ is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, it should be zero at the boundary, but I guess I can't say u=0, because u does not have to be continuous. **Can someone clear up this? HOw do I conclude u =0 ?**

Additionaly the rest of the proof I did it like this, for instance , for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$\|\nabla (\alpha u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}= |\alpha| \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$

$\|\nabla  (u+v)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}  = \|\nabla u + \nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}  \le \|\nabla  u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla  v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$

But I am not sure, since I guess I have to use the fact that $\Omega$ is polygonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you use the definition
$$
H_0^1(\Omega)=\overline{C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)}
$$
where the closure is taken in the Sobolev norm. Furthermore, the trace operator is continuous, that means:
$$
T:H^1_0(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)
$$
is a continuous linear operator assigning boundary values to a Sobolev function. This is where you need your domain to be polygonal: It has a Lipschitz boundary, which is a requiremnt for the trace operator to be well defined and continuous.
Now, you can use the equivalence of defintions
$$
u \in H^1_0(\Omega) \iff u \in H^1(\Omega) \; \textrm{and }\; Tu=0.
$$
and note that the trace operator agrees on functions continuous up to the boundary $u \in C( \overline{\Omega }) $. Since $u(x)=c \; a.e.$, you can chose the representative $u(x)=c$, dropping the almost everywhere and conclude that $Tu=0 \iff c=0$.

Comment: Why can I choose a representative? I a choose another one I don't get 0.... so how can that be the same?

Comment: Representatives are only determined almost everywhere. And the trace operator assigns the same boundary values regardless of the representative. Remember that, when dealing with $L^p$ spaces, your are dealing with equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: So the rest of the axioms in the proof are OK?...Don't I need , for instance , in the second one.. to express the L^2 norm as a sum over the domain partitioned such that every subset contains only a side of the polygonal border? Like a triangulation ?

Comment: Why would you want to triangulate your domain for show that this is a norm? The fact that the boundary is polygonal implies that it is a (locally) Lipschitz boundary which you require for the trace operator. 
The rest of your proof is fine.